# HTTP Deployer throws "Attempt to load JVM failed on native side"

Tags: tridion

On Tridion 2011 SP1, after I just restarted an HTTP Deployer, I get the error "Attempt to load JVM failed on native side" when I try to access HTTPUpload.aspx.

What is the issue?

I added an env variable JAVA_HOME, restarted the server, but no luck so far.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind... It seems that after rebooting the server AGAIN, problem was fixed.

I guess I'll never know what was it.

Answer (score 1):

The story is way deeper than initially believed and it all boils down to memory allocation.

The culprit in my case was the heap size that we allocate to the Java process running underneath IIS (in JuggerNET). I have 4 CD instances (4 websites running each a CD stack) on 32bit server, with memory 4GB. The heap size was set to 1024M. Naturally there was not enough memory to allocate 4GB of heapspace.

Reducing the heapsize OR stopping a website solved the issue.

Heapsize is controlled in registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Tridion\Content Delivery\General\jvmarg1
```

with value `-Xmx1024M`.

Another culprit might be mixing CD DLLs from 64bit with 32bit servers, so check and double check your DLLs!!! I know I did :) hours long...