# Contact Profilesync.aspx throws "Attempt to load JVM failed on native side"

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

**Brief Summery** : We are using Tridion 2011 SP1 with out any hotfix, and a .net web application as Synchronization server (Profilesync.aspx) to synchronize the contact of subscription db and audience manger db. Also we are using Java 6.

**Problem** : After completing the installation when we hit the "Profilesync.aspx" page, it gives the error "Attempt to load JVM failed on native side".

**Error** :

```
Attempt to load JVM failed on native side

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 


Exception Details: Codemesh.JuggerNET.JuggerNETFrameworkException: Attempt to load JVM failed on native side

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[JuggerNETFrameworkException: Attempt to load JVM failed on native side]
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.Load(Boolean bAcceptPreloaded) +287
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader.Load() +41
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init() +111
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject() +49
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1082
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr() +54
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle() +50
Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args) +390
Com.Tridion.Marketingsolution.Utilities.TcmUri..ctor(Int32 publicationId, Int32 itemId, Int32 itemType) +160
Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.Utilities.Settings.set_ConfigFileName(String value) +51
Tridion.OutboundEmail.ContentDelivery.OutboundEmailPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) +153
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +12
System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +140
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +480
```

Can some one help me to find whats going wrong.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Usually this means that there is a mismatch between 32bits and 64bits files (dll's) in combination with the installed Java version. If you installed the 64bits version of Java, be sure to also use the 64bits version of the SDL Tridion (OutboundEmail) Content Delivery dll's. Same goes for the 32bits version of Java; Use the 32bits version of the SDL Tridion Content Delivery dll's.

Answer (score 0):

If Albert's post doesn't do it for you (although what he says is *very* correct), have a look at the same issue I had here [HTTP Deployer throws "Attempt to load JVM failed on native side"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238273/http-deployer-throws-attempt-to-load-jvm-failed-on-native-side).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to leave some notes to help somebody in the future.
If you verified that the proper .dlls were used but yet still encountering the error (Attempt to load JVM failed on native side).

Try uninstall all java run time in the system and re-install it back cleanly (install JRE 64-bit first)

I have seen this has helped resolved an issue for a customer of mine.